# How can I make a Recylerview with expandable feature inside card (Triggering with scrool position)

Tags: java, android

I have classic recyclerview but i want to make expanded recyclerview with triggering when it hits a specific top position. How can i make it. Can you show a way or suggest me anything about that?

I want to make like that:

[image]

Comment: please share some code

Comment: I have classic recyclerview. It pulls data from SQLite and show. I want to make it like that. When the top item reaches a specific top position it will trigger the recyclerview view and expand. According to that it will change the Imageview as well.